# Is it ok to use MongoDB / MapReduce to solve my following case?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mongodb, mapreduce

Considering the following illustration where Letters are Group and numbers are elements :

[image]

### Considering the following problematic :

Each group have right to only get for each shared elements : Math.ceil(nb elements / 2)

**Meaning A can get elements :**
- 1 (shared with D)
- 1 or 2 (shared with B)
- 3 or 4 (shared with C)

So A can have **max 3 differents elements.**

**B can get elements :**
- 1 or 2 (shared with A)
- 1 (shared with D)
So B can have **max 2 differents elements.**

**C can get elements :**
- 3 or 4 (shared with A)
So C can have max **1 differents elements.**

**D can get elements :**
- 1 (shared with A)
So D can have max **1 differents elements.**

Now my question is :
Is it possible to use mapreduce or another thing to obtain these results with mongoDB ?

> The result i am waiting is the following :

```
>A => 3  
>B => 2  
>C => 1  
>D => 1
```

How could be the Collection schema to be able to perform the mapreduce (if possible ?

(currently for my tests i was using this :

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c1603c"),
    "lead" : 1,
    "pdv" : "A",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "B", 
        "D"
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c1603d"),
    "lead" : 2,
    "pdv" : "A",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "B"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c1603e"),
    "lead" : 3,
    "pdv" : "A",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "C"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c1603f"),
    "lead" : 4,
    "pdv" : "A",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "C"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c16040"),
    "lead" : 1,
    "pdv" : "B",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "A", 
        "D"
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c16041"),
    "lead" : 1,
    "pdv" : "D",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "A", 
        "B"
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c16042"),
    "lead" : 2,
    "pdv" : "B",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "A"
    ]
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c16043"),
    "lead" : 3,
    "pdv" : "C",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "A"
    ]
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512d8a5aa9e92bfc3c16044"),
    "lead" : 4,
    "pdv" : "C",
    "etat" : "p",
    "conc" : [ 
        "A"
    ]
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean you're going to reduce over that collection, not over the groups?

Comment: This is currently the collection I have, but the structure / scheme can be another proposal : I do not have fixed the schema of the collection because I am currently making some testing to have the result described.

Note : there is a mistake in my problematic description : you should read : each group have right to get only : math.ceil(nb elements / nb group sharing these elements)

Comment: I don't understand your result. `A` has access to 4 shared elements, not 3. You want to calculate the number of different groups with which a group has at least one shared element?